# Animation moves clothes on torso even though only leg bones are rotated

Tags: modeling

Fairly new using blender. I am trying to place a jacket mesh on a model. I have added the armature modifier from the model and transferred the weight from the rig/model to the mesh, however when I try to add a simple animation to the hip/thigh bone, the jacket is following that animation and is "ripped" back exposing the skin. Anybody know what is going on here?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is that the jacket mesh is moving when leg/hip bones are rotated, which is unexpected, since the jacket should not be influenced by those bones or at least was not intended. I am asking how to prevent the jacket mesh from being moved when the leg/hip is rotated.

Comment: When the body mesh moves correctly and the jacket is a separate mesh you can try to transfer the weights from the body to the jacket with the *Data Transfer* modifier.

Comment: Yeah, I think I sort stumbled upon that in my quest to fix this, the mesh stays in place now the weight is 0 on all the lower extremities. However I discovered it may also be due to the fact that the mesh is not properly attached to the rig. When I move an arm the armor does not follow (which may be the initial underlying issue, the weights are just  dealing with a symptom not the root cause).

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out through some intense fiddling. I selected my jacket mesh and went into edit mode, clicked x-ray and selected the entire mesh, clicked on the green triangle button to display the vertex groups, for each of the bones in the legs I set the weight down to 0 and clicked apply (I had to go into pose mode to figure out what they were all called). After that my the mesh stayed in place. I am sure I will have a lot of "fun" with all the other meshes I plan to make...  There are likely better solution for this since it seems quite elaborate, that you would need to do this every time you make a new mesh.